# Points that are quadrilaterals

Tags: polygons

When are 4 points in a plane considered quadrilaterals? Also, could you give me examples of 4 points that are not considered quadrilaterals? Thank you in advance!

Comment: A quadrilateral is a four-sided shape, not a collection of points. What would you expect to find here that the first paragraphs of the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) wouldn't give you?

Comment: Did you mean when do 4 points form the vertices of a quadrilatetal? In that case you just want two make sure no three points are co-linear. So a bad example would be choosing 4 points on the same line. They can not be turned into a quadrilatetal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition varies depending on the user and the application, but the biggest challenges are 1) three points in a line, so an angle is $\pi$:  $(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,1)$, 2) a crossing quadrilateral $(0,0), (2,0), (0,2), (2,2)$, 3) a concave quadrilateral: $(0,0), (10,0), (10,10), (9,1)$

$\hspace{1.5cm}$[image]

Comment: I hope you don't mind the addition of the images. Feel free to delete if you wish.

Comment: @robjohn:  thanks.  I think they help.